# Listing acknowledgements on CV as a final year undergraduate student?

Tags: publications, research-undergraduate

I have read a lot of threads on this forum and others where listing acknowledgements in research papers on CV is mostly advised against, but then again it seems like most of these advice are directed towards people who already have publications under their belt. As an undergraduate student, I participated in some experiments and got acknowledged in papers. So, I was wondering if it is okay to list that in my CV as a sort evidence of my involvement in research studies. Or would it still look like I'm trying too hard to find something to fill my CV with? FYI I'm submitting my CV to an academic for a research position

Edit: wording

Comment: What sort of "position" are you applying for? Doctoral study? Something else?

Answer (score 4):

It would still look like you are trying too hard to find something to fill your CV.

On the other hand, you can put your involvement in those research studies as working/education experience. No need to provide proof for them: either your referral will mention "I supervised OP during his activity in the research study XYZ" or these things will be discussed/asked at the interview.

The important point is whether you fully understand the paper you have been acknowledged, that you can discuss them, or if you simply participated in the data collection/collection of data preparation/data pruning.

If you fully understand the papers, you may think of bringing/mentioning them at the interview, discussing how much you learned and understood while helping in that study, if you are not ready to discuss them in depth better to leave them rest in peace: you were not the author, but you proved yourself you can contribute to the authors'work.

I personally think you are not ready to discuss the content of the papers, since you are "only" in the acknowledgments, but you show you can contribute to research work in a dependent way (i.e. you were not in the authors) and you feel you can do independent research work (i.e. you think you can be author of a scientific publication in the near future).

Good luck!

Comment: *not ready to discuss the content of the papers, since you are "only" in the acknowledgments* --- As an example for the OP, I'm cited in the Acknowledgment section at the end of [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/31/8/016/meta?casa_token=uQBEruwtxw4AAAAA:1PL1SpQNFq6VRtEU0uk8cxwQeMYHNpMxEKelLLWm2S6jThGpgrcMak2m2VDBQut9BjBHRVkOhB6KOyLwCw6B), but I know essentially nothing about anything in the paper. To a lesser degree, this also applies to a few other papers . . .